# Could not invoke A0Auth0.showUrl

Tags: react-native, auth0

I am using Auth0 to do the authentication. On iOS, react-native-auth0 runs perfectly.

However, when it comes to Android, the error comes out:

[image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `customtabs` version in `node_modules/react-native-auth0/android/build.gradle`

from

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:23.3.0'
}
```

to

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:23.0.1'
}
```

Fixed it for me and others.  Courtesy of: https://github.com/auth0/react-native-auth0/issues/67#issuecomment-322209597